# Ansible command loop amend string value and push original value into new array

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, ansible

Hi I'm using ansible to create some elastic search indexes using laravel's artisan commands. The issue I have is that when I have to create an index I have to use the php class name which the base name is snake cased from camel case e.g. UserConfigurator = user_configurator. In my vars I have the following;

```
elastic_search:
  version: 6.3.2
  indexes:
  - "App\\ElasticSearch\\Configurators\\UserConfigurator"
  - "App\\ElasticSearch\\Configurators\\ClientConfigurator"
  models:
  - "App\\Models\\User"
  - "App\\Models\\Client"
```

and in my playbook I have the following;

```
- name: check if indexes exist
  uri: url='http://localhost:9200/{{ index_name }}'
    method=HEAD
    status_code=200,404

- name: create indexes
  command: php artisan elastic:create-index "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{site_root}}"
  with_items: "{{elastic_search.indexes}}"
```

The playbook isn't sufficient enough to do what I want to do due to lack of experience. Any ideas how I may loop over each elastic_search.indexes and convert the class basename to a snake case and check to see if the index exists or not and push them into two separate arrays so then I can use the one of the new variables to create the index and the other variable to update the index?

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how I may loop over each elastic_search.indexes and convert the class basename to a snake case

The algorithm I use for snake-casing something is to break the word at an upper-to-lower boundary, lowercase the entire thing, then reassemble the parts, being mindful that the *first* upper-to-lower transition is special and should not be separated by `_`.

We can leverage the behavior that when `set_fact` sees a block of text that looks like JSON, it will coerce that block of text into a `dict` (you'll see that behavior on the command line with `ansible -e '{"hello": "world"}'` too), along with the infinitely handy `regex_replace` jinja2 filter provided by ansible:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    class_names:
    - 'App\ElasticSearch\Configurators\UserConfigurator'
    - 'App\ElasticSearch\Configurators\ClientConfigurator'
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      index_names: >-
        [
        {% for cn in class_names -%}
        {{ '' if loop.first else ',' }}
        {{ cn |
           regex_replace(".*\\([^\\]+$)", "\1") |
           regex_replace("([A-Z])([a-z])", "\x00\1\2") |
           lower | replace("\x00", "_") | regex_replace("^_", "") |
           to_json }}
        {% endfor %}
        ]
    with_items: '{{ class_names }}'
  - debug: var=index_names verbosity=0
  - debug: var=item verbosity=0
    with_items: '{{ index_names }}'
```

which produces the correct output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=user_configurator) => {
    "item": "user_configurator"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=client_configurator) => {
    "item": "client_configurator"
}
```

and now you can use those indices in a command of your choosing.